# configure ObjectDataSource from Code Behind in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ObjectDataSource and I want to configure it from code behind , I want to set the InsertMethod , Selectmethod from Code Behind and set it to my Business Layer files

Please help me as soon as you can

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code behind, you can assign the SelectMethod and InsertMethod like this:

```
this.ObjectDataSource1.TypeName = "NamespaceName.ClassName";
this.ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod = "SelectMethodName";
this.ObjectDataSource1.InsertMethod = "InsertMethodName";
```