# Inserting into ObjectDataSource with an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I am attempting to learn ASP.NET and want to use an ObjectDataSource to select and insert into a database.  I am using a business class that has an insert method that has an object as its parameter.  Several sources I've looked at say that this is a correct way of doing this but I have been unable to find out how to insert into the database using c# in the code behind file.  I have a form that pulls from two other tables using ObjectDataSources that work correctly but I need to use a button to insert the record that I am creating into the table.  I do not seem to be able to add the object I have created into the InsertParameters of the ObjectDataSource so I want to know if there is a method of doing this.

The insert method's signature looks like this:

```
public static void InsertIncident(Incident incident)
```

The ASP code that Visual Studio generated looks like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
  DataObjectTypeName="Incident" InsertMethod="InsertIncident"
  OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"  SelectMethod="GetIncidents" 
  TypeName="IncidentDB"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Have you checked out this link.http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=9878983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a little bit silly now, but I found out what I was doing wrong.  I didn't need to use the ObjectDataSource for inserting the object at all.  I should have just called the insert method directly.

```
if (IsValid)
{
  Incident i = new Incident();
  i.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCustomer.SelectedValue);
  i.ProductCode = ddlProduct.SelectedValue;
  i.DateOpened = DateTime.Today;
  i.Title = txtTitle.Text;
  i.Description = txtDescription.Text;

  try
  {
    IncidentDB.InsertIncident(i);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I had the same issue and this helped me find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your ObjectDataSource into something like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="Incident" InsertMethod="InsertIncident" SelectMethod="GetIncidents" TypeName="IncidentDB"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Then, try to add DetailsView to insert the record in your database:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="insertData_DetailsView" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="400px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" GridLines="None">
```

Just make sure that you have the correct DataSourceID in your DV.

It works fine for me.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to use a detail view but a set of controls that do not work well with one.  As such I want to use a button.  The reasoning is that I want one item in the table not to be shown in the form but set automatically (the current date) and two more left null.  The DetailsView does not really work for this task.

Comment: Hi Steven, have you checked this [Configure ObjectDataSource from Code Behind] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900398/configure-objectdatasource-from-code-behind-in-c-sharp) ?